# AWS API gateway drops empty parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I would like to use the API gateway to implement an already defined API interface.

An example request would look like this:

```
Request: /?action&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

In my Lambda function I only can see the parameters with values, but not the parameter `action`:

```
"queryStringParameters": {
  "param1": "value1",
  "param2": "value2"
},
```

If my request looks like this :

```
/?action=delete&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

then I can see the parameter `action`:

```
"queryStringParameters": {
  "action": "delete",
  "param1": "value1",
  "param2": "value2"
},
```

Is this a kind of limitation? In https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html I am not able to find any hint.

I also tried to work with the proxy integration, but with no luck. :(

Comment: I initially suspected the missing `=` after `action`.  However, I can't reproduce this no matter what I try (using Lambda proxy integration).  I always get an empty string for `action`, whether the request looks like `/?action&` or `/?action=&`.

Comment: @MikePatrick: Can you give me a short description of what you have configured in your API gateway or a screenshot? I think there is a small mistake in my configuration and I can't find it.

Comment: I'm just using default lambda proxy integration on a GET, with no additional configuration.  No headers, querystring params, or anything else defined.  FWIW, I also could NOT reproduce this when using a body mapping template *instead* of lambda proxy integration. Perhaps you can update the question with more details about your APIGW configuration? If you're using a body mapping template, what does it look like?  If you're using lambda proxy integration, what else is configured?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I deleted my whole API and created a new and absolute simple one. With only one get method and the proxy integration. But this time I did not used the method test in the API gateway - instead, I used Postman. 

What I can see is the following: The URL is 

/?serverinfo&contentRepo=2b 

in Postman and in the AWS test method. But the result is a different one. The response with Postman shows an empty querystringparameter and the response with the AWS test method does not show the empty querystringparameter.